# What are the potential technological advances that the discovery of the Higgs boson may unlock?

Tags: higgs, technology

Lately I have been reading a lot about the discovery of the Higgs boson and it got me thinking, what is the potential application of this particle? I mean can the Higgs Boson change our world the way the discovery of the electron has?

For example: The Higgs Boson is what gives all other particles mass, could this be manipulated in a way that would allow us to create potentially massless objects, like an engine that would essentially take the mass away from an object?

My question is this **What are the potential technologies that could be developed that use the Higgs boson?**

Comment: Hi Jonn_Underwood, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I don't think this question really fits here for a few reasons: first, it's pretty open-ended. In principle, there could be an endless list of technological developments resulting from a particular physical discovery. And besides, the technology that emerges from a discovery isn't really a part of physics. That's where the engineers take over.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to search the site for similar questions before asking a new one: you find your answer quicker that way! This question is an obvious (good) one that has been asked many times; this appears to be the 'official' version: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31293/practical-matter-of-the-higgs-mechanism.

Comment: @Mark ah, thanks for finding that! (Don't forget, you can always flag a question as a duplicate)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I wasnt sure if it would be an ok question to ask, I was going to ask on meta if a question like this would be ok, but read the FAQ and thought it would fit under the second (I believe) example of the "questions to ask"

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky way ahead of you bro :) . By the way, I don't agree that asking about technological applications should be considered "off-topic", it's definitely part of why we do physics. The problem is that historically, scientists are extraordinarily bad at predicting what their research will be useful for!

Comment: @Jonn_Underwood don't worry about it. This isn't the sort of thing that second FAQ item is meant to include, but if you're not sure if a question is OK, the right thing to do is just go ahead ask it - we don't hold it against you if it gets closed. As you can see, there's some disagreement about what is on topic and what isn't.

Comment: @Mark fair enough. This category of technological questions might be something to discuss on meta, if there isn't already a meta question about it.